# Investigating Unknown Network Error in Firefox

Tags: firefox, networking, console, firebug

There is something weird happening on the website of the company I'm working for.

On both Firefox and Firebug console log, I get an unknown network error.

There is no code reference for the error, and I can't track it on other browsers.

However, it's there, and I don't know how to solve it, nor what it is.

Other sites with the same theme, same domain registrar and on the same server work just fine, showing no problems at all.

What the heck is that??

[image: Unknown NetworkError in Firebug]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the latest update of Contact Form 7 Plug-in solved the problem!